# Unable to use Next.js getStaticProps with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am trying to use getStaticProps with TypeScript, first I tried with a function declaration:

```
import { Movie } from './movies/movie'
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'

export async function getStaticProps(): GetStaticProps {
    const res = await fetch('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/horizon-code-academy/fake-movies-api/movies');
    const movies: Movie[] = await res.json()

    return {
        props: { movies }
    };
}
```

In this case I get the error: Type '{ props: { movies: Movie[]; };' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticProps'

I have tried the alternative types `GetStaticProps<{ movies: Movie[] } >` and `Promise<GetStaticProps<{ movies: Movie[] } >>` but none of these work, I still get the wrong return value. After reading some answers on Stackoverflow I realized most seem to be using arrow functions for this, so I also tried:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/horizon-code-academy/fake-movies-api/movies');
    const movies: Movie[] = await res.json()

    return {
        props: { movies }
    };
}
```

It does not let me use arrow functions, I get the error: "getStaticProps" is not a valid Next.js entry export value.

I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Hi, in your first snippet you are typing the return value of the function as _GetStaticProps_: it won't work because _GetStaticProps_ is supposed to be the type of the function itself.
The arrow syntax looks correct. Can you make sure your file has a _.tsx_ extension and is located directly under the _pages_ folder (root > pages > component.tsx)?

Comment: @clementlize indeed it was the folder structure that was the problem, I did not know that my pages folder needed to be in the root folder, rather than in the app folder

Comment: Now I have the problem that the routing does not work (when I go to localhost:3000/movies, or any other folder in the pages folder, I get 404) however this is another question to ask!

Comment: @naean Yes this would be another question I think. Try to find existing questions, I'm sure you're not the first one to encounter this problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it did not work was because my component was inside the app folder, when it needed to be in a pages folder inside root folder in order for getStaticProps to work. I got confused is because I did not know about the new App Router way of building Next.js applications, and I was mixing the old way with the new way. I was following a two years old tutorial, and had chosen to use app routing when creating the app, which lead to the app folder being created instead of the pages folder. It seems that with the new paradigm we are no longer supposed to use getStaticProps. More information here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration